# pg_restore: [archiver (db)] SET row_security = off

Tags: postgresql

I just installed a new postgresql 9.5 server on  Windows

I have an error message when I'm trying to restore the DB.

> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while INITIALIZING: pg_restore:
>   [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  unrecognized
>   configuration parameter "row_security"
>       Command was: SET row_security = off;

What causes this?

Comment: My guess is that your pg_restore executable actually comes from your previous installtion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`row_security`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-ROW-SECURITY) configuration setting is new in 9.5, and that error indicates that you're restoring a database dump taken from a 9.5 database into an older version of PostgreSQL.

That combination is not supported, as new features can't work with old servers.

When developping on a local database and deploying to a remote database, development should happen on the **same major version as the remote**.
Up to version 10, Postgres uses an `X.Y.Z` convention, where `X.Y` is the major version, and `Z` a minor revision that adds only bugfixes to `X.Y`.
Starting with version 10, it's `X.Z` where `X` is the major version and `Z` the revision number.

Comment: This happens even if the dump itself is from the older version but you're using a newer version of pg_restore.

Comment: Data looks restored properly but still, each DB raised the error messages while restoring. There will be any impact if I ignore the error(s) related to row_security?

Comment: @Spike: if the ignored errors consist only of `SET row_security = off;` it just means that the target database does not support that feature, which is harmless. If the source database actively used this feature you'd have other errors related to the creation of policies.

Answer (score 3):

I was using pgAdmin3 from a new MS 10 desktop to edit a server running Postgres 9.3. The pgAdmin3 v1.22.1 produces this 'row security error'. I reinstalled the pgAdmin3 as v1.20.2 and the error no longer appeared.

Comment: What a lifesaver. Basically, BigSQL's pgadmin doesn't seem to like this security_row flag, but older pgadmins don't seem to mind.